# SOQL Query for Account - Junction - Account

Tags: soql, custom-object, sql, junction-object

I need to join Account (type = person account) --> Junction Object --> Account (type = business account)

We have person accounts enabled on our org. I can easily write what I need in SQL, but writing it in SOQL has proven difficult. Can you assist in writing a SOQL statement that pulls fields from person/customer account and business account?

SELECT * FROM
Account as customerAccount
JOIN Junction__c ON Junction__c.customerID__c = customerAccount.ID
JOIN Account as businessAccount ON businessAccount.ID = Junction__c.businessID__c

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to use the relationship fields to do what I need.

Object CustomerCompanyRelationship__c has two custom fields, CustomerAccount__c and
CompanyAccount__c, both lookups to the Account object.

Select
CustomerAccount__r.ID, CustomerAccount__r.Name
CompanyAccount__r.ID, CompanyAccount__r.Name
from CustomerCompanyRelationship__c